# C Using pointers with a 2D array of a struct and how to access them using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, 2d

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    char last[25] ;
    char first[25];
};

struct seating {
    struct student **seat;
};

//Set the first and last name to default values
void student_init_default(struct student *s ) {
    strcpy(s->last_name,"***");
    strcpy(s->first_name,"***");
}

void seating(int rowNum, int columnNum, struct seating *a ){
    //Instantiate a 2D array specfied by the parameters
    struct student students[rowNum][columnNum];

    a->seat = students;

    //Initialize each element to the default
    for(int rows = 0; rows < rowNum; rows++){
        for(int columns = 0; columns < columnNum; columns++){
            student_init_default(&students[rows][columns]);
        }
    }

}

void main() { 
    struct seating room; 
    struct student student;

    int row, col, rowNum, columnNum; 

    char student_info[30]; 

    // Ask a user to enter a number of rows for an classroom seating    
    printf ("Please enter a number of rows for an classroom seating."); 
    scanf ("%d", &rowNum); 

    // Ask a user to enter a number of columns for an classroom seating   
    printf ("Please enter a number of columns for an classroom seating.");   
    scanf ("%d", &columnNum); 

    // seating
    seating(rowNum, columnNum, &room); 

}
```

To start off, I am a beginner at C. My problem is using pointers. The main point in this code is to make a 2D array of the **struct student** and then fill in the array by setting the default as first and last name. What Im asking for is if someone can give a easy explanation or hints on how to connect the parameter, **struct classroom_seating *a**, with **struct student **seating**, along with the 2D array. Along with that, how would I use **struct classroom_seating *a** to access the 2D array? I do know the basics of pointers but I've been researching for hours and haven't found a connection to work.

I do know that this line **printf("%s", listOfStudents[0][2].firstName);** prints *** (assuming the user entered 3,3 for row/columns). It's that I don't know how I would be able to access that in later methods.

Comment: I guess you worked out the problem from answer provided.

Comment: As pointed out by *coderredoc*'s answer below already you are trying to assign to `a->seat` something that does not fit. But even if it would fit the code would not make you happy as `struct student students[rowNum][columnNum];` is defined *locally* to the function `seating()`, so the moment the code returned from this function all memory `a->seat` pointed to would have become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
a->seat = students;
```

The compiler is explicit about the error

```
error: cannot convert 'student [rowNum][columnNum]' to 'student**' in assignment
     a->seat = students;
             ^
```

is wrong because  here you are assigning a 2d array to a double pointer. 2d array decayed into `struct student (*)[]` and then you tried to assign it to `struct student **`.

Instead you should create the jagged array yourself and work with it.

```
a->seat = malloc(sizeof(struct student*)* rowNum);
if(!a->seat){
   perror("malloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for(int i = 0; i< rowNum; i++){
   a->seat[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct student)* columnNum);
   if(!a->seat[i]){
      perror("malloc");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

After that you can pass the address of each `struct student` instance like you did and make changes to it.

To clarify further about the organization that you are likely to follow

- `struct seating room;` Here `room` is a structure instance containing a double pointer. That's it. That pointer points to no where significant. It contains indeterminate value (garbage value).
- Now you want to allocate some memory and work with it. That is being done in the function `seating`. As it is just a pointer, you allocate memory of `rowNum` `struct student *` and why `struct student*`? Because that in turn will point to a series of `struct student` variable instance.
- After successful allocation, now you have the memory and it is not of automatic storage duration - it will stay when the function `seating` ends also. It's storage duration extends beyond the scope of the function.
- Notice one thing, `strcpy(s->last_name,"***");` but there is no `last_name` variable in the structure definition. It would be `last`. Same goes with other member variable also.
- After making the changes you would pass the instance of `struct student` like this:-

  ```
  for(int rows = 0; rows < rowNum; rows++){
      for(int columns = 0; columns < columnNum; columns++){
          student_init_default(&a->seat[rows][columns]);
      }
  }
  ```
- You are trying to assign to `a->seat` something that does not fit(not possible). But even if it would fit it would be wrong as `struct student students[rowNum][columnNum];` is defined locally to the function `seating()`, so the moment the code returned from this function all memory `a->seat` pointed to would have become invalid. Accessing it would be undefined behavior then. (alk pointed this).

Comment: @alk.: Edited..Thanks.